# Modifiying Spring Url in an aspect like way

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-rewriting

I am looking for a way how to modify the urls within the `spring:url`- tag implementation, without modifying the jsps.

A short introduction, to explain what I want to do:

I have a application that heavy use `<spring:url` in the jsp.

Stuff like this:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/style/default.css" var="css_url" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${css_url}">
    <!-- required for FF3 and Opera -->
</link>
```

but the same for images, ...

Now I want to changed the mapping for the resource folder a bit, so that it include the current version. (So for version 1.0.1 `/resources/style/default.css` become `/resources1.0.1/style/default.css`) (*before somebody ask: the reason is caching*)

Of course I do not want to modify all the `spring:url` tags in all jsps when I release a new version. So my first idea was to add a new ModelMap variable (VERSION) and then modify all url tags once (`<spring:url value="/resources${VERSION}/style/default.css" var="css_url" />`). -- This works.

But I am looking for a better way, for example a way to "inject" the version in the `spring:url`- tag implementation. So that the tag itself replace all `/resources/` by `/resources1.0.1/` (or what ever the current version is). So I am asking does somebody **have an idea how to adding some code to the `spring:url`- tag implementation that modifies the urls?**

(*I don't want to use someting like tuckey UrlRewriteFilter, or want to change the mapping, I really want to modify the output of spring:url*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd either have an application context property and use normal JSP EL, or create a custom tag (e.g., `<app:versionedUrl>`) that encapsulates whatever logic you want to use.

By keeping the property in the context you can play some games with slow-rolling a new version, allow specific users/groups/etc. to "freeze" on a version, etc. as well if that's something interesting to you.

Another option would be to create a mapping for CSS files that include a version ID and either forward to the actual resource or stream back the version-specific content.

Comment: I have created a custom tag that extends the spring UrlTag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters to map URLs with /resources* and then modify the request.